# R: Histogram subtitle with mtext: how to get tabular alignment in columns?

Tags: r, alignment, subtitle

I have a plot with a multi-line subtitle:

[image: multiline subtitle plot]

Current code for the text:

```
bq1 <- bquote("Raw: "
              ~ mu 
              ~ "=" 
              ~ .(format(round(mean(stepsperday$steps), digits=2), big.mark=","))
              ~ ", " 
              ~ sigma 
              ~ "=" 
              ~ .(format(round(sd(stepsperday$steps), digits=2), big.mark = ","))
              ~ ", median ="
              ~ .(format(median(stepsperday$steps), big.mark = ","))
)

bq2 <- bquote("Imputed: "
              ~ mu 
              ~ "=" 
              ~ .(format(round(mean(stepsperday.imputed$steps), digits=2), big.mark=","))
              ~ ", " 
              ~ sigma 
              ~ "=" 
              ~ .(format(round(sd(stepsperday.imputed$steps), digits=2), big.mark = ",", digits = 6))
              ~ ", median ="
              ~ .(format(median(stepsperday.imputed$steps), big.mark = ","))
)

mytext <- list(bq2, bq1)
mtext(do.call(expression, mytext),side=3,line=0:1, cex=.75)
```

I would like the 2 lines horizontally aligned on the respective bits of data - the means, sd, median, like they're in a table.

Is there any way to do this?

thanks for any tips,

sff

Comment: I got pretty good alignment by putting 7 blanks in front of "Raw"  in `bq1`

Comment: call mtext twice, once for `raw\nImputed` once for the rest, use a different adj

Comment: thanks @RichardTelford - doing mtext column-wise as you suggest, with a strategic placement of spaces per g5w 's suggestion worked. 

was hoping for a more "structural" solution but oh well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

per the comments, the following is adequate:

```
data1 <- "      Raw:"
data2 <- "Imputed:"
mytext1 <- list(data2, data1)
mtext(do.call(expression, mytext1), side=3, line=0:1, adj=c(.23, .23), cex=.75)

bq1 <- bquote("  " ~ mu 
              ~ "=" 
              ~ .(format(round(mean(stepsperday$steps), digits=2), big.mark=","))
              ~ " " 
              ~ sigma 
              ~ "=" 
              ~ .(format(round(sd(stepsperday$steps), digits=2), big.mark = ","))
              ~ " median ="
              ~ .(format(median(stepsperday$steps), big.mark = ","))
)

bq2 <- bquote("   " ~ mu 
              ~ "=" 
              ~ .(format(round(mean(stepsperday.imputed$steps), digits=2), big.mark=","))
              ~ " " 
              ~ sigma 
              ~ "=" 
              ~ .(format(round(sd(stepsperday.imputed$steps), digits=2), big.mark = ",", digits = 6))
              ~ "   median ="
              ~ .(format(median(stepsperday.imputed$steps), big.mark = ","))
)

mytext <- list(bq2, bq1)
mtext(do.call(expression, mytext), side=3, line=0:1, adj=c(.6, .6), cex=.75)
```

Which yields output:

[image]